# Bootstrap Javascript Not Loading in Hello World Simple Project

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, bootstrap-4

**For some reason the JavaScript isn't displaying. I've checked the inspect element sources and it does in fact load correctly, however it isn't being applied. Any idea why? Thanks.**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
```

**app.js:**

```
require('./bootstrap');
```

**I'm specifically wanting dropdown menus to work and also the bootstrap carousel from the bootstrap website:**

```
<div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need recompile your assets.

```sh
npm run watch
```

or

```sh
npm run prod
```

Comment: that wasn't it. it renders the app.js just fine in the browser, but for some reason it isn't applying the javascript.

Comment: Oh ok, Try moving your script line above the closing body tag.